# Are we going to be able to easily see the separate up-votes and down-votes on a post?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, voting, information-display

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Show Total Votes (or Up/Down Votes)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/747/show-total-votes-or-up-down-votes)

*This has been asked before on UserVoice, but I'll ask it here as well.*

Currently the "votes" reported against a post are the net votes (up-votes - down-votes). Are we going to get an easy way (tooltip, AJAX expander, etc.) of finding out the individual scores.

One reason I ask is that I'm trying to go through deleting answers that nobody has voted on and are just one of many answers to a question so don't really add anything to the site. However, there is a difference between an answer that truly has no votes and one that has equal numbers of each type. In this case someone has found it useful even if someone else disagrees. It might also make me try to improve the answer too.

If nothing else, deleting the latter type of answer will cost me some rep.

Comment: Same as http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/747/show-vote-totals-or-up-down-votes which has more votes & discussion. (Even if this was posted earlier.)

Comment: I wasn't going to say anything, but this question has just been down-voted without explanation. Now while you have every right to to that, I would have thought that on a site who's primary purpose is discussion leaving a comment as to why you think this is a bad idea was pretty much essential. Sorry if this comes over sounding petulant, but I really do want to know what was so wrong with the question that you felt a down-vote necessary.

Comment: The idea itself of deleting "stale" answers sounds not good at all. Why would you do that? DB space consumption? Those answers are at the bottom of the page anyway, but might help someone.

Comment: @EFraim - I only delete those answers that have score <= 0 and don't add anything to the sum of Stack Overflow knowledge. I also don't do it very often.

Comment: Deleting answers just because they have no upvotes is a pretty terrible idea. Every opinion adds value to the site, even if no one has found it valuable enough to upvote yet.

Comment: @theotherreceive - I only do it when my answer is substantially the same as other answers to the question. If mine's the only answer or if  it adds new information I'll leave it.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to see your Positive vs. Negative score on your questions and answers by looking at your Reputation graph. If you include your entire timeline, you should have the scores on the right side that show the Positive vs. Negative.

Comment: @TheTXI - That's been mentioned before, yes you can do it that way but it's not that easy to operate (or is that just me?)

Comment: ChrisF: I would agree that it's definitely not the most user-friendly way to finding the information. Just pointing out that the information IS there already in some fashion.