# Show Total Votes (or Up/Down Votes)

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, voting, user-interface

When viewing *any* question, it would be nice to see the **total number of votes** as a little tagline underneath the total vote score.

[image]

It would be nice to see the difference  between:

```
+0 (0 votes)      <-- of little interest (0 up, 0 down)
```

versus

```
+0 (214 votes)    <-- controversy (107 up, 107 down)
```

You could show the individual up/down totals (+12, -15) but I thought a simple total might be somewhat cleaner.

Comment: Related to my question? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/604/are-we-going-to-be-able-to-easily-see-the-separate-up-votes-and-down-votes-on-a-p

Comment: +1 for the graphical illustration

Comment: Maps to this uservoice item: http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com/pages/1722-general/suggestions/133215-see-upvotes-and-downvotes-as-well-as-net-votes

Comment: yeap i always liked how Urban Dictionary provided a better picture of what the community felt over a post, allowing me to count the population who possess a certain view.

Comment: - 1 for improperly formatted image!

Comment: Sorry, this post is 5 months old, long before we had the technology to draw freehand circles and Godzilla charactures.

Comment: @Robert C. Cartaino, In light of that I guess I should reverse my vote, however my vote is too old to be changed. So if you edit your post I can change it, but now that the technology is available when you edit your post you would have to update the image to a properly formatted one and then I can change my vote :-p

Comment: hopefully now that we've implemented this people can see how relatively useless (IMO) of a feature this is, because downvotes are statistically so rare.

Comment: Loving this new feature

Comment: The possibility to perform heart transplantions is relatively useless (IMO), because heart failures are statistically so rare.

Comment: The ability to show vote counts is insignificant next to the power of the force.

Comment: +1 to split votes into 2 part ( Up-voting / Down-voting )

Comment: As far as I know, Reddit.com shows the percentage of upvoters.

Comment: The feature is not fully completed, as it has 1000 rep requirement

Answer (score 79, accepted):

The total vote count (score) is denormalized, but the individual up/down vote counts are not.

So to display it on every post would incur 2 vote table queries * number of visible questions / answers. Our DB is fast, but the vote table is pretty massive, and *not* doing a query is always faster than doing it..

It's possibly something we could do on demand (as @hmemcpy notes), but as an "always displayed" it is a non-starter.

(Also: downvotes are still quite rare on Stack Overflow, so I'd say about 90% of the time, when you see a score, it is pure upvotes.)

EDIT: **Jarrod implemented displaying total up/down votes today**. This is currently deployed to meta and will be deployed to other sites in the evening PST later today. Simply click on the vote number itself to show up/down vote totals. Requires 1000 rep.

Comment: I had a feeling that denomalization would be the reason why this hasn't already been implemented. Just thought I would ask.

Comment: Ok I'll bite... you're denomralizing the net votes. Why not just denormalize the up and down votes too? 200k questions * 10 answers on average each * 8 bytes (on the outside) per post = 16MB of data.

Comment: This is like part of your reason for not showing the post which achieved a badge: "we don't have that data." Yes, you *currently* don't have the separate votes denormalized, but the system can change. I don't think it's a good idea to use "we're not currently set up to make this change trivial" as a reason against a feature request.

Comment: Just doing my bit to make downvotes that little bit LESS rare.  Sorry Jeff, I think this is a pretty weak excuse.  You have blogged and spoken about how the SO team has overcome tons of other technical difficulties to make the site faster/better/stronger.  What makes this problem so different?

Comment: The new addition by Jarrod is nice, but it doesn't *undo* (i.e. you should be able to click again to set it back to the total count).

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why the 1k rep requirement?

Comment: @gnostradamus:  I was going to say the same thing.  Looks good, but can't go back.  Thanks for the update!

Comment: Personally I'd be happy with tooltips but I guess that involves putting that information up whether someone wants it or not whereas this is on-demand. Anyway, this is a welcome change. Thanks Jeff. Now if only you can solve the mystery of the missing "Return to Question" link. :)

Comment: tooltips are a bad idea because 98% of the time, the score you see is all upvotes anyway. So making it on-demand is more sensible, since from my perspective this is "information porn" anyway.. prurient, not really necessary. :)

Comment: Nice implementation! An example for those who don't have 1,000 reputation: http://img.skitch.com/20091220-8b116etdgx7e83wwxsmaxxs81d.png

Comment: yeay, a feature for the 100-ish people who have 1,000 reps...(on meta, that is)....and no, of course I'm not one of them ;-)

Comment: If it cannot show the total number of votes, perhaps it should phrase it in a less misleading manor. like "14 score" or 14 vote score" or "14 upvotes" because technically "14 votes" is inaccurate.

Comment: @Jeff is it your plans to implement @gnostradamus feature? Though it is not vital to the site's functioning, I find it very counter-intuitive that when you click, and get it by up-votes down-votes, when you click it again nothing happens. Thanks

Comment: Is this still the case Jeff? Have up/down counts been denormalised into the post?

Comment: Does this performance issue still persist in SE network? This answer has been shared [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/69854/286110) as an answer. I was looking for an updated answer for this old [question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/69852/286110). Should I consider your answer as a valid answer to the said question, or do I need to dig more for another answer, perhaps offer a bounty on question?

Comment: It's actually a shame this feature is available only to 1000+ REP users, because the users who would most benefit from it, are the inexperienced. I've noticed the odd question or answer where there seems to be real negative momentum, but reading it I can't help feel that some people must be being bit hasty, seeing a negative total and jumping on the band wagon. It's obviously (I assume, please let it be so) the more inexperienced users who would do this one would think. Users relative statistical tendency towards controversy would also be a fascinating statistic for da management possibly...

Comment: "downvotes are still quite rare on Stack Overflow, so I'd say about 90% of the time, when you see a score, it is pure upvotes." For any post with 50+ score it's possible to find the one who downvotes. Maybe just for fun.

Comment: @Michael And it is not implemented on every site.

Comment: How about [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/236767/260388)?

Comment: "downvotes are still quite rare on Stack Overflow, so I'd say about 90% of the time, when you see a score, it is pure upvotes." @JeffAtwood - Do you happen to have actual numbers backing up that claim that users can be directed to? I'd be very interested in seeing the total up-votes to down-votes in any given period.

Answer (score 41):

An unobtrusive way of showing the information would be as a **tooltip**, shown when hovering over the score (or perhaps the up/down arrows).

Comment: perhaps as a JQuery tooltip w/ background query that would work, but as a HTML tooltip, has same problems as noted in my answer.

Answer (score 33):

Another way could be something like Digg, where upon clicking on the number of diggs, it toggles:

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

However this wouldn't work quite well here, so perhaps show this in a tooltip over the number, as Jonik [suggested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/747/show-total-votes-or-up-down-votes/1003#1003).

Comment: this was an excellent suggestion and the inspiration for our implementation of the feature (now live on meta.. click the vote #, if you have 1k rep)

Comment: Awesome :)   (15 chars)

Comment: @JeffAtwood is this likely to ever be rolled out for those of us with lower reps?

Answer (score 20):

I've created a UserScript/bookmarklet which enables this feature for all Stack Exchange websites.
If you don't have sufficient reputation, let alone an account, you will still be able to view up- and downvotes.

For more details, see ["View Vote totals" without 1000 rep](https://stackapps.com/q/3082/9699?view-vote-totals-without-1000-rep).

If you're not interested in details, but want to use the script right away, have a look at [GreasyFork.org](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/6192-stack-exchange-view-vote-totals-without-1000-rep).

Comment: Thanks. That's brilliant. Nice UI too.

Comment: any way to get this to work on Area51? There it's *really* useful to know which questions are controversial.. It works on discussions there, but not proposed questions.

Comment: @naught101 My userscript / [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/view-vote-totals-without/oibfliilcglieepgkdkahpfiiigdijdd) is using the Stack Exchange API (v2) to get the data. Area51 is not available through the SE API. Related posts on Stack Apps: [Why I think Area51 needs an API.](http://stackapps.com/questions/1234/why-i-think-area51-needs-an-api) and [List Area51 discuss in the StackAuth sites list](http://stackapps.com/questions/1957/list-area51-discuss-in-the-stackauth-sites-list).

Comment: Awesome Chrome extension!! Interestingly, it worked on ELL meta, but not on Ask Ubuntu meta. Any idea why?

Comment: @Fiksdal Thanks for letting me know... I accidentally put spaces after the URL pattern that ought to have matched meta.askubuntu.com. I removed these spaces and now the extension also works on Ask Ubuntu meta (version 1.5.8).

Comment: @RobW Awesome, it works now.

Comment: [Said Rob W, *“Fog makes an excellent curtain, but a poor wall.”*](http://thecodelesscode.com/case/87)

Answer (score 14):

Moderators and 10K rep users get access to the **vote velocity**, or the amount of upvotes and downvotes for a given question.

Given that this information is already available, I can only surmise that it wasn't included for one of the following reasons:

1. Performance hit for providing that information for every action request on the site.
2. To not 'encourage' excessive voting (both up and down) for a topic.
3. Because it's not really 'important' across an aggregate context.

Comment: I have 14k rep on StackOverflow, and I don't see how to access this vote velocity...

Comment: @Thomas: http://stackoverflow.com/tools/votes-hot, or tools -> links -> recent questions with most vote velocity

Comment: Ah. Well, it should be displayed on the question page.

Comment: I vote for #1, #2, and #3.. at some level this is kind of information porn, it's prurient and not really all that necessary for typical use of the site.

Comment: man, I have to get to 10k

Comment: Unless I just haven't found it, you can't view this on an arbitrary question/answer.  this information is only provided for the 100 questions/answers on the votes-hot page

Comment: @JeffAtwood How is knowing the ratio of up votes:downvotes more prurient than knowing the total? It adds more information, which allows users to make better informed decisions on which answer to trust.

Answer (score 6):

It might make sense to show it on a users own question, since they basically can see this information by the reputation they gain/loose.

If you really want to know, you can determine this easily enough using the [SO data-dump](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/stack-overflow-creative-commons-data-dump/)

I'm not really sure what you gain by having the information easily visible, since it could be misleading (say if a question was crappy, so it was down-voted, edited then voted back to a positive number). I think the final score is all that really matters..

Comment: Actually, this might be an application for Complex Event Processing...for example, to know when the number of up-votes and down-votes are roughly the same (perhaps +- a percentage of the total votes), resetting after an edit.