# When did upvote/downvote splits get added to Meta?

Tags: discussion, voting, statistics

I've only just noticed that you can click on the aggregate vote count on a question or answer in Meta, and see the split of upvotes and downvotes.

As far as I can tell, this isn't live on Stack Overflow yet... when did it come to Meta? Have I been asleep for weeks?

Any news on when it'll come to the other sites?

Comment: How did you even notice that? If it weren't for this question, I doubt I would have seen it.

Comment: @alex - The cursor now changes to a hand when hovering over the vote total, so I'm guessing that's how Jon noticed.

Comment: @alex: Jon has a daily ritual of going over each pixel on SO/Meta. :)

Comment: @cletus: If that were the case, I'd have seen Jeff's update ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It happened [earlier today](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/747/show-total-votes-or-up-down-votes/1007#1007) on Meta. It should show up later today on the other sites.

Comment: Thanks - hopefully this question will get it a bit more coverage :)

Comment: Yeah, it's easy to miss.

Comment: Beat by seconds. Amazing how fast you can get an answer sometimes.

Comment: This feature rocks my world!

Comment: That answers one of my requests which was actually a duplicate of this question - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/747/show-total-votes-or-up-down-votes

Comment: Shame you have to click through to the question or answer though and can't get at the split from your profile page.

Comment: @ChrisF: absolutely; or that you can't click somewhere and have all up/down votes shown for every post on the page.

Comment: Is there a required rep score? I don't see it.

Comment: @Henk - If you follow the link in the question you'll see that you need a rep of 1000 to be able to use this feature.

Comment: Chris, you mean the link in the answer. But I found it, thanks.

Comment: Why the 1000 Rep requirement?

Comment: It would appear one can only fetch one set of vote stats per second.