# Split answer count?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, voting, vote-count

I found this today:

[uh? http://img25.imageshack.us/img25/2457/capturadepantalla200912.png](http://img25.imageshack.us/img25/2457/capturadepantalla200912.png)

How come?

If I click on upvote or downvote the "split" disappears.

Here's the [video](http://www.vimeo.com/7930708) if you want to see it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a feature, not a bug.

See [Show Total Votes (or Up/Down Votes)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/747/show-total-votes-or-up-down-votes/1007#1007):

> Simply click on the vote number itself to show up/down vote totals. Requires 1000 rep.

It's rate limited to one request per second.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why the 1k rep requirement?

Comment: @AnonJr To reduce the number of calls to the database that are made.