# Turn vote count off?

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Toggling between net votes and plus/minus votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41218/toggling-between-net-votes-and-plus-minus-votes)

Finally after I reach 1000 rep (yeah, puny, I know), I rushed to one post and clicked on the vote. To my ecstasy, the vote count showed up!

However, I find that despite being very useful, the vote count's color is a bit distracting. So I clicked it again...

What!? Not closed?

I click it again. No prevail.

Is it possible that we could have another way to close the vote count other than refreshing the page (assume that you are using a 56K modem and every bit counts)?

Answer (score 13):

You can just re-vote. Whether it goes through or not (if your vote is locked in), the votes will collapse again.

Comment: Okay, that's kind of a solution to this. THX!

Comment: +1, I didn't know this worked even for locked-in votes.