# Confused about the thing you get at 1000 rep

Tags: support, reputation, privileges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Show Total Votes (or Up/Down Votes)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/747/show-total-votes-or-up-down-votes)

**1000    Show total up and down vote counts**

*What does that mean?*

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it. *More interesting things are possible* when you reach 2000.

Comment: I'm just trying to figure out what I get at 100k - I suspect "OCD".

Comment: Thanks, I was confused by the exact same thing! And I don't think the "possible duplicates" at the top are actually duplicates.

Comment: It's a thingadongdong

Answer (score 20):

Instead of the total you can see the number of upvotes and the number of downvotes when you click on the total, 18 upvotes and 1 downvote in this example:

[image]

---

---

If the page is refreshed then the original state is restored.

Comment: Oh! I thought that thing was a bug!

Comment: +1, After 10 months, I accidentally found this :)

Comment: What do you mean accidentally? haven't you read all other questions already? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8211/hidden-features-of-stack-overflow/31491#31491

Comment: @Juan Manuel : Yes Juan, I didn't read, and I can't read all other questions. As you linked, it's a really *hidden* feature.

Comment: WOW , I didn't realize I had to click on it

Answer (score 11):

A post can have score of 837, for example.

When you reach 1000 rep, you can **click on the post score number, and it will expand** to show that the score of 837 consists of +862 upvotes, and -25 downvotes.

[image: Voting details]

It's awesome.

[Show Total Votes (or Up/Down Votes)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/747/show-total-votes-or-up-down-votes)

Comment: Could you guys be more precise, who I have to downvote for this lame image?