# How do I "Show total up and down vote counts" since I'm at 1K rep?

Tags: discussion, reputation, voting, help

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Confused about the thing you get at 1000 rep.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33490/confused-about-the-thing-you-get-at-1000-rep)

I'm supposed to be able to see the total up/down votes, but I'm way above 1K rep and I still don't see any of [these](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/747/show-total-votes-or-up-down-votes).

So how do I see the breakup of votes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Click the number.

```
   ▲
   / 
 (100}  <--- Right there!
   _
   ▼
```

Comment: If anyone knows how to do ASCII freehand circles, feel free to try.

Comment: Done. Just don't ask in the future ;)

Comment: That's the most horrible freehand circle I've ever seen in my life. If you'll pardon me, I think I'll go develop an irrational phobia now.

Comment: Mission accomplished!

Comment: Uh, in my country that's how we say "Thank you." Your country is same, yes?

Comment: We don't say "Thank you" in my country :]