# Voting UI bug when clicking the vote number rather than up or down (screen shots)

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, voting, user-interface

Using Google Chrome (3.0.195.38) and IE 7 (7.0.5730.11IC)

If I click on the vote number (not up, not down)

[alt text http://www.86th.org/bug1.jpg](http://www.86th.org/bug1.jpg)

It turns into this

[alt text http://www.86th.org/bug2.jpg](http://www.86th.org/bug2.jpg)

and then this

[alt text http://www.86th.org/bug3.jpg](http://www.86th.org/bug3.jpg)

In IE, the 5 and 0 are seperated by more space.

Edit: ok ignore the "2" in the second picture, I just took a screenshot of the wrong vote.  It does indeed stay as a "5".

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31687/bug-during-upvote/

Comment: A nice example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/164432/what-real-life-bad-habits-has-programming-given-you/164556#164556

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a feature unlocked at 1k rep.

see:
[Show Total Votes (or Up/Down Votes)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/747/show-total-votes-or-up-down-votes)

Comment: Ah, nice, looked like a bug.  Would be nice to see +5 -0, so we could understand what was going on.

Comment: Look at your tooltips, Allen.

Comment: I see that (now), but + and - would not be incorrect and it would make the tool tip obsolete.

Comment: I like the idea of adding + and -.

Comment: well, it wouldnt completely make the tool tip obsolete, but it'd be easier to see whats going on

Comment: Badass, they added the "+" and "-" :-D