# Update meta with all the features of SO

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Show Total Votes (or Up/Down Votes)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/747/show-total-votes-or-up-down-votes)

I know, I know. This is a question for meta.meta.stackoverflow.com but common :)

I like being able to see how many up-votes / down-votes a question has by clicking between the arrows like you can on SO and other little things like that. I don't know how much work is involved though in keeping each site caught up to the others features.

Comment: its a dupe, you need 1000 rep

Comment: Meta is usually the first place the features are released on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That particular feature only works if your reputation is high enough (though I don't know what the limit is). Your rep on SO is probably much higher than on meta - I have the same problem.

Answer (score 4):

This is linked to reputation. You need a 1000 reputation points to be able to see it.

You can see the reputation table on the FAQ [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're not clicking hard enough. It works for me.

[See? http://img717.imageshack.us/img717/6857/circle.png](http://img717.imageshack.us/img717/6857/circle.png)