# What exactly is that we achieve at 1000 reps?

Tags: discussion, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What privileges are given to a 1000 reputation member of Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33311/what-privileges-are-given-to-a-1000-reputation-member-of-stack-overflow)

I am not sure what is it related to..

```
1000     Show total up and down vote counts
```

Thanks

Comment: Thanks. It is not duplicate, but duplicate of duplicate

Comment: That duplicate has been deleted now...

Answer (score 8):

You get what was requested here: [Show Total Votes (or Up/Down Votes)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/747/show-total-votes-or-up-down-votes)

Click on the vote count to the left of a question or answer, and you will see how many up- and down-votes it has received.

[image: click and see the wonderfulness]

Comment: :( Your freehand circle isn't complete.