# I achieved 1000 rep, but I don't see the up/down vote counts per the FAQ

Tags: support, privileges, vote-count

I've achieved 1000 rep points, but I don't see the up/down vote counts for some reason, as 
shown in the top answer to:

[Image of up down vote counts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37864/what-exactly-is-that-we-achieve-at-1000-reps-closed)

What do I need to do in order to see them?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Click on the total score between the vote arrows.  It is an on-demand feature.

See https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/view-vote-counts

Comment: Aha, I wish that was mentioned in the FAQ...

Comment: @Michael, It says *after click* in the image you linked to.  I added a link to the privileges page that clearly shows it.

Comment: Sorry, I must have been blind :) .

Answer (score 0):

This is a link fro the Help section that shows how to do it:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user

Comment: I just saw when this question was first posted, hm interesting it was at the top of my feed for active questions- must have been bumped up, oh it was just edites

Comment: Yes, you are correct. It was [edited](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/67844/revisions) thus bumped up. I humbly suggest that you edit the previous answer to fix the link (which you have mentioned) and delete your answer.

Comment: @AzizShaikh I have been told it is unwise to delete my questions or answers, as if I do it too frequently I can get a post ban. You can downvote it and/or flag it

Comment: Well you have a valid point but the main thing here is **too frequently**. :) I can't downvote because it is a correct answer after all. Anyways, lets keep it there.

Comment: @AzizShaikh em, yes, I should have explained myself, I went through my account and deleted out all the posts I was not happy with, like house cleaning and then it was revealed to me I could get a post ban, so now I don't delete anything, I have already pushed it ;) thnx for your input though.. which is kind of good discipline, it's teaching me to look before I leap, like with this one, never thought to check the date of the question