# What exactly does "see votes" mean?

Tags: support, voting, vote-count

I have just reached 1000 and can apparently now "see votes", though for the life of me I cannot find anywhere were I can see votes and see nothing different from before I obtained this privilege.
What exactly is "see votes", and how do I access this privilege?

Comment: Is the section [How do I view vote counts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/established-user) in the privilege page unclear? Related: [I achieved 1000 rep, but I don't see the up/down vote counts per the FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67844/289905).

Comment: @SebastianSimon the user is still a novice, only a member for 24 days. If we look at the privilege page on Skeptics there is no image to enlighten newcomers. https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges. Users have to click on the wording in order to see the graphics

Comment: @Mari-LouA [I see an image](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/established-user) on the skeptics page.

Comment: @RobertLongson  But not on the privilege page, the first page a user will probably land on,  that was my whole point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the left of this question and this answer is a score. If you can see votes, you can click on this score and it will split into two numbers that added together are the score. One is the number of upvotes, the other is the number of downvotes.

Here's a screenshot of this very question with the score expanded into votes. Upvotes are above in green, downvotes are below in red.

[image: see upvotes]

Comment: The [help center page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/established-user) for the privilege even has a picture! :)