# Reduce the amount of rep required to view upvotes and downvotes

Tags: feature-request, reputation, voting, api, score

In the FAQ it says:

> **1000** Show total up and down vote counts

I'm not sure why you need 1000 rep to do this.

It's possible to find this information out [via the API](http://bit.ly/bl5xFV) (and the data dumps) so it's only a matter of time before someone creates a Greasemonkey script to show this data.

Comment: Meanwhile there indeed is an app to circumvent this 1k rep restriction via the API, see the [VoteCount bookmarklet](http://stackapps.com/questions/557/votecounts-bookmarklet-to-display-up-down-votes-even-for-rep1k).

PS: Your 'via the API' link is broken (or rather has been broken by publishing the [API Version 0.9, Release Candidate](http://stackapps.com/questions/871/api-version-0-9-release-candidate) ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This information is available in the data dump and through the API, but in a sense it's still far less "available" than being able to see the information on every post at any time. I believe there was a performance argument for not allowing this function below a certain rep threshold (maybe Jeff can give us some numbers on that).

As Jeff said [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40480/please-enable-low-rep-users-to-easily-breakout-up-and-down-votes-on-their-own-que/49757#49757), he thinks this should be an ability you earn (I can see both sides to that).

I think it would be *most* useful in the form of the [feature-request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40480/please-enable-low-rep-users-to-easily-breakout-up-and-down-votes-on-their-own-que) to allow < 1000-rep users to view the voting split on their own posts. That would satisfy this request in a meaningful and useful way, while not negatively affecting database performance too much.

Comment: The total numbers of upvotes and downvotes aren't listed in the schema, but you can see details of individual votes.

Comment: @Simon: You're right, my bad. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 5):

We had to have something special for those who reach 1K rep.