# Default to show total up/down votes?

Tags: feature-request, voting, vote-count

Is there any way to get the total up/down votes to be shown by default?

Is it considered to be not interesting / relevant to people? I guess it doesn't drain the server that much more... The nice detail would be more obvious if it was shown directly on page load instead after a click as there is a huge learnability issue now.

Comment: Your guess is wrong

Comment: Is there some more links to blog posts or something that discusses the issue? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/747/show-total-votes-or-up-down-votes/1007#1007 was the first, I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR - I don't  think this will be a good idea.

---

As Jeff explains [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/1007/152859) and Robert explains [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/40484/152859), the reason for not showing this by default is the complexity of the query.

Since that stat is not cached, it means running an expensive query on each page load (even of users with 1000+ reputation, it means thousands of those every hour on Stack Overflow) thus wasting server resources for no good reason. Most of the people aren't really interested in the vote count, and those who are can simply click the score.

Answer (score 2):

There is always the possibility to utilize e.g. a Greasemonkey script on FF:

```
function doNextSplitAndRepeat() {
  $($('span.vote-count-post:not(:has(div))')[0]).click();
  if ($('span.vote-count-post:not(:has(div))').size() > 0) {
    window.setTimeout(doNextSplitAndRepeat, 1050);
  }
};

doNextSplitAndRepeat();
```

This way we can also incorporate the time delays mentioned in the comments below. The resulting userscript is available at [userscripts.org](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/79298).

It should behave well enough, i.e. make only one req/sec. and click each vote only once.

Comment: This is will get you banned, at least temporarily, just a heads up :)  If you visit pages with large numbers of answers you'll easily trigger the ~15 requests/sec ban limit.

Comment: @Nick Additionally, even with less than 10 answers if it attempted all of the clicks within 1 second it wouldn't get very far because you can only fetch one split-vote-count per second.

Comment: Ok, good to know.

Comment: Edited the script accordingly.