# Should users be able to view vote counts on their own questions?

Tags: feature-request, vote-count

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Please enable low-rep users to easily breakout up and down votes on their own questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40480/please-enable-low-rep-users-to-easily-breakout-up-and-down-votes-on-their-own-que)

By looking through my reputation history, I can reverse engineer the vote count for a question I've asked. I understand from looking through questions and finding [Why is it a privilege to view vote counts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69852/why-privilege-to-view-vote-counts) that the reason for limiting this privilege is to reduce the computational burden on SO, but it seems that allowing a user to view counts on his/her own questions shouldn't add too much of a strain.

Comment: I appreciate the irony that this question note has a "+3" but it will take a bit of work for me to discover how many people have voted (though at least I know it's an odd number:)

Comment: There's really no reason to worry about this type of thing. The net score is all that matters... If *that* even matters.

Comment: @Cody Gray: I'm not *worried*, but on meta in particular, the number of votes is almost as important as the score itself.

Comment: I fully agree with you, here on Meta it is particularly helpful to see the vote breakdown. (Incidentally, you've got 3 downvotes right now.)