# Allow OPs to view upvotes and downvotes on their questions

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, voting, vote-count

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Please enable low-rep users to easily breakout up and down votes on their own questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40480/please-enable-low-rep-users-to-easily-breakout-up-and-down-votes-on-their-own-qu)

Currently, users need to have [1000 reputation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/established-user) in order to view the vote counts on any question. However, OPs already have extended privileges on their own questions, without the needed rep (for instance, they can close, view close votes, etc.).

Because vote counts are useful information for OPs, I suggest that OPs should be able to view the upvote and downvote counts on their own questions, without the needed rep.

Comment: Not against this, but in the initial stages at least, that's easy to follow by looking at your rep.

Comment: @Mat True, but having vote counts available is more convenient for the OP.

Comment: Exactly; you can calculate it easily manually, it's just nicer if this privilege is granted. +1

Comment: I didn't notice there was a duplicate. Thanks for telling me. (By the way, that question is almost *two years old*; why hasn't anyone acted on it?)

Comment: @mc10: it's declined - [see the reason given here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40480/please-enable-low-rep-users-to-easily-breakout-up-and-down-votes-on-their-own-qu/49757#49757)

Comment: You can can't really vote to close your own question *or* view close votes without the needed rep. It just happens that the rep bar for your own questions is a lot lower (250 for your own questions vs. 3000 for other questions).