# "Votes" is not a good representation of activity on a question

Tags: discussion, voting, visibility

On the front page of any SE site every question has tallies for Votes, Answers and Views. However, Votes does not properly tally the actual amount of votes, rather it shows the net total of vote values.

A million positive versus an equal amount of negative votes will show 0, a misleading number for a VERY active question.

Would there be a better way to represent the actual question activity?

EDIT: As suggested, what I would prefer the number to say is the total number of votes - positive and negative. It's a fairer indicator of activity.

Comment: Different view, but I think that number should just be renamed to "score", because that's what it is.

Comment: @Bart Not a bad view. It at the very least would make the number less ambiguous.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/286897/show-the-vote-split-by-default

Comment: @MichaelFreidgeim Rather an inverse, with different ends, viewed in a different place.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to view the actual amount of upvotes and downvotes. The privilege to view vote breakdowns are granted when you earn 1000 reputation on MSE.

From the privileges page:

> Voting scores, as displayed, are the sum of the up and down votes on a post. Vote counts are the individual up and down votes that make up the score.
>
> You can view the vote counts by clicking on the score of a post. This
>   will break the score into upvotes and downvotes, like so:
>
> [image: vote count click]
>
> The upvotes have a plus sign next to them and are displayed as the top
>   number, in green. The downvotes have a negative sign next to them and
>   are displayed as the bottom number, in red.

You may refer to [this help page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/established-user).

Comment: Even still, the total NUMBER of votes would be a more accurate respresentation of activity - rather than the breakdown or the net.

Comment: So pressing the downvote button increments the number by one? Or do you propose a total rework of the voting button?

Comment: Yes, Upvotes or downvotes should increment the number by one, I would think. On the front page, not on the question itself.

Comment: You might want to clarify that in the question

Comment: Done. Thanks for the clarification request.