# Votes breakdown in meta

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign

There is a votes breakdown on stackoverflow but doesn't appear to be on meta.

How come this hasn't been implemented for meta? I was wondering if there was a specific reason or if it was in the pipeline?

This is what I mean for those who don't get me:

[image: Vote Breakdown]

Have a nice day!

Comment: `but doesn't appear to be on meta` It is, you just don't have the rep for it (yet).

Comment: So...will this be tagged `[status-norepro]` or `[status-completed]`?

Comment: @UristMcBobby I'm thinking [meta-tag:status-bydesign].

Comment: @UristMcBobby [status-deferred] more likely, you know for when OP gets 1K Meta rep ;P

Comment: I never understood why this feature needs to be unlocked, it's very useful and impossible to abuse.

Comment: Aah, sorry, I didn't realise that this was a required rep feature. My apologies.

Comment: @Wes it's a bonus for long time member that's all. Like the removal of new user restrictions once he gets to 10 reputation, and various statistics when getting to 10K reputation (via moderator tools) - if one really want to see details for voting he can manually go to the question timeline e.g. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/137106/timeline

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd: Seems unfair to hide valuable info like that. It's important to know when an answer with a positive score also has a ton of downvotes. I always check the vote totals before assessing the value of an answer I'm not sure about. There's a big difference between a -0/+1 post and a -99/+100 one.

Comment: See http://stackapps.com/questions/3082/view-vote-totals-without-1000-rep

Comment: @WesleyMurch not really, what matters most if the final score which *is* visible. If you feel it's so important feel free to suggest feature request asking to always show that breakdown and see how the community respond. :)

Comment: @SomnathMuluk love that extension!!!

Comment: @WesleyMurch: If I remember correctly, this is also a privilege to reduce hits on the database, as the request for those votes is rather expensive.

Comment: @UristMcBobby: I can't imagine how it would be more expensive than just loading another page, like the vote timeline for example. Now we have all kinds of ajaxy stuff like live vote totals, alerts for new answers, live question feeds - I think that is a poor excuse, although it may be the official one. I think those numbers are important to those of us seeking help, they should be easily available on request.

Comment: @WesleyMurch: [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/40484/136489).

Comment: @UristMcBobby: I maintain my opinion that it is a poor excuse, especially considering all the other existing new features that burden the server.

Comment: I'd love to know the breakdown of up and down votes on this question.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's still here. You just need to get 1k reputation here on meta stack overflow, as it has a separate reputation count.

On all other metas however, you only need 1k rep on the main site, as meta shares your rep there.

Comment: Correct. Viewing vote counts is part of the [Established User](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/established-user) privilege.

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned, you need 1000 rep to view the vote totals legitimately - but there's a Greasemonkey script you can use in the meantime that works for all SE sites and metas:

["View Vote totals" without 1000 rep](https://stackapps.com/questions/3082/view-vote-totals-without-1000-rep)

> The vote counts are a great tool to determine whether an answer is disputed or not. Unfortunately, not many of us have enough time to join all Stack Exchange websites and get 1000 reputation.
>
> This script unlocks the "View Vote counts" feature, without 1k reputation requirement or being logged in.

Thanks to [Rob W](https://stackoverflow.com/users/938089/rob-w) for this contribution.

Comment: I wouldn't use this. It undermines the philosophy of SO, in that you are rewarded for your reputation.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: Personally, I believe it should be accessible to everyone, even unregistered users, so they can assess whether or not an answer is disputed. This helps people make better decisions.

Comment: It's explained here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/747/show-total-votes-or-up-down-votes. Getting the up/down votes is no small matter, so the 1k rep barrier is to keep their servers running as fast as possible. Its a feature that not many users care particularly about, so why give them the option when you can have faster servers instead?

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: The post you link to requests that the numbers be displayed without clicking, resulting in extra overhead by default whether a user wants it or not. *"the 1k rep barrier is to keep their servers running as fast as possible"*... laughable, but plausible.

Answer (score 0):

You can also view this by looking at the posts [timeline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36303/feedback-request-new-timeline-question-view) (as you can on all sites), for example:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/137106/timeline