# Show total up / down votes on one's own posts

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, vote-count

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Please enable low-rep users to easily breakout up and down votes on their own questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40480/please-enable-low-rep-users-to-easily-breakout-up-and-down-votes-on-their-own-qu)

With 1000 rep, one can see total up/down votes on any post.

My request is that one can see total up/down votes on one's own posts, without any special rep requirement.  This information is already available, although not easily digested, by looking at ones own reputation history, so it wouldn't be an information leak.

Comment: @random: Thanks for pointing out the duplicate... that I couldn't find when I searched.