# Vote count breakdown for the owner of post

Tags: discussion, feature-request, vote-count

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Please enable low-rep users to easily breakout up and down votes on their own questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40480/please-enable-low-rep-users-to-easily-breakout-up-and-down-votes-on-their-own-qu)

The vote count break down which is accessible after achieving the privilege 'Established User' which is set to much higher reputation on all child SE sites should be a feature provided to all users with no reputation restriction(or minimum may be 50 or less) for the posts they own.

My concerned feature is this

[image: vote count]

Especially on MSO, where there is really both kind of voting(up and down) in a very rigorous manner, it's hard for the post owner to keep track of it. So, atleast the owner of post must be able to see this break down without any reputation restriction for just his own posts.

Considering meta again, I don't say to lower the 'Established User' reputation benchmark point, but make this feature avaiable to post owner at low reputation cost, please.

Have seen other post on MSO in reference to vote-count, which says the execution  expense of the query is large, due to which this feature is provided for high rep users only, But again as I recall from some answer I read, The query won't be more expensive on MSO than on SO considering the data size.

#### NOTE

This feature request is not only for MSO, but for all child SE sites.

Hope my question is clear.

Comment: Hmm. I see a `status-declined` to it which was 2 and a half years back. Does it now have any probability?

Comment: The [stackapps](http://stackapps.com/questions/557/.) answer to same question, solves this problem easily.