# Should owner of Question/Answer be able to see the up-vote/down-vote

Tags: feature-request

I think it can be helpful to the OP to be able to click on the vote and it shows the up-vote/down-vote.

> It would be better if the owner of the question/answer should also see them.

Comment: The dup is status-declined ...

Comment: And there is [at least on other try to suggest this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147747/vote-count-breakdown-for-the-owner-of-post) notice the link to [this stackapps thingy](http://stackapps.com/questions/557/votecounts-bookmarklet-to-display-up-down-votes-even-for-rep-less-than-1000)