# Weird behavior when up-voting an answer?

Tags: support, up-votes, behavior

This is not affecting me in any way :). But I am just curious to understand the reason behind it. Sometimes when trying to up-vote an answer from '0', I get the following state:

[image: screenshot]

On clicking the up-vote button again, it's displaying properly. Is it a bug? If not, why is it coming only sometimes and not always. I am seeing this in both IE8 and Firefox 3.5.8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you didn't click on the up-vote arrow, but a little lower on the number of votes.

What you're seeing is [a new feature that got implemented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/747/show-total-votes-or-up-down-votes/1007#1007) (actually it isn't that new anymore).

It's only available to users with more than 1000 rep though. Maybe that's why you only start seeing it now (or recently)?

Comment: Yeah... Got it.. Thanks! I can only find it in my SO account(am over 1000 there only) and not on SU or MSO.