# What happened to the up/down vote count (vote details)?

Tags: support, vote-count

What happened to the [up/down vote counts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/747/show-total-votes-or-up-down-votes)? They were showing last week on SO but now they seem to be gone?

Comment: Not sure I agree with this being closed as "too localised". It's always going to be the case that people hit the case where abilities and features disappear due to lost rep. Having questions and answers that cover this is a good thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You appear to be under 1,000 reputation on Stack Overflow since setting up a 500-rep bounty. The up/downvote splits show up at 1,000, and yes, you do lose privileges if you fall under their threshold after the fact.

You'll still see them on Server Fault, though.

Comment: Ha! I had no idea I needed 1,000 rep, not sure how I missed that, Thanks!