# Why cannot I see the breakdown of + and - votes on Stack Overflow like I can on Programmers?

Tags: discussion, voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What happened to the up/down vote count (vote details)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41561/what-happened-to-the-up-down-vote-count-vote-details)

When I am on Programmers, I can click on the vote and see how many ups and downs there are. Why cannot I do this on Stack Overflow?

Comment: It's because you don't have 1,000 reputation on Stack Overflow. Check the [privileges page](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges) for what abilities you get at what reputation level.

Comment: Thank you. Wish you had this as an answer so I could accept.

Comment: I was sure that the question was effectively a duplicate, but I can't find it.

Comment: @ChrisF yes, it seems vaguely familiar to me as well... ;-)

Comment: @TheUnhandledException Unfortunately the answer to that question doesn't link to the privileges page. Perhaps a merge is in order.

Comment: You're right. His answer was suited to me because it talked about that bounty I did way back when. Your answer is a far better general answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's because you don't have 1,000 reputation on Stack Overflow.

Check the [privileges page](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges) for what abilities you get at what reputation level.

These are consistent for all graduated sites. The reputation levels on beta sites are lower and on private beta lower still.