# Purpose of showing total up and down votes?

Tags: discussion, support, reputation, voting

Across the Stack Exchange network, when a user reaches 1K rep, the user is able to see the total up and down votes.  *What is the purpose of this?*

Thanks!

Comment: Because they needed something at 1k. But, don't trust 1ks enough to edit stuff. Lol, idk.

Comment: Somebody asked this in a comment on [the original meta announcement](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/747/show-total-votes-or-up-down-votes/1007#1007), but I don't think it was ever answered

Comment: The history of [the originating feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/747/show-total-votes-or-up-down-votes/) explains all, I guess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Robert said it well in the [original debate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/747/show-total-votes-or-up-down-votes/) about this. (Thanks for that link @Mrozek)

It would be nice to see the difference between:

> +0 (0 votes)      <-- of little interest (0 up, 0 down)

versus

> +0 (214 votes)    <-- controversy (107 up, 107 down)

Answer (score 1):

Because some of us wanted to see the breakdown of votes.  It was made 1K probably so that there was something for those who reached that level.