# Number of Upvotes and Downvotes in Meta

Tags: support, vote-count

This may be a weird question (also, there's no meta-meta SO, so I have to post here).

I know that on SO, I can click on the score of any question or answer and see how many up/down votes it has received. However, this is not the case on meta. I was wondering why I can't see the number of up/down votes for a post on meta?

Comment: +1 Meta-Meta! (and i was looking for this question..)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to the [Privileges page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/established-user), you need to have 1000 reputation in order to see vote counts on a Stack Exchange site. This means that you have gained enough reputation to be an "Established User". Unlike most other Meta sites, Meta.SO has its own reputation so even if you have over 1000 reputation on Stack Overflow, you'll need to also gain 1000 reputation here.

For an explanation of why this privilege is reputation-limited, see [Why is it a privilege to view vote counts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69852/why-privilege-to-view-vote-counts)

Comment: Ahh. Thank you. It has been a while since I've hit 1000 rep on SO and therefore "don't remember a time when...". Thank you for the answer (accepting after the timeout in 8 minutes)

Comment: Why just not hide current votes number until 500 rep?