# Why is viewing vote count of a question/answer a privilage?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why privilege to view vote counts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69852/why-privilege-to-view-vote-counts)

I feel that the ability to view vote counts should be a base feature. There's nothing about it that requires the system to "trust" the user, since this feature is harmless, and it can make the site more helpful to people by providing additional information regarding the quality of an answer. For example:

If a certain answer has a total vote sum of 10, it can be because everybody agree that it's correct (10 ups, 0 downs; everybody agree), and it can also be controversial (80 ups, 70 downs) but slightly biased towards the up votes. I would be much more inclined to trust a 10/0 answer than an 80/70 answer. In some situations, an answer that has almost the same number of conflicting votes is as good as an answer with a negative number of votes, but I wouldn't be able to tell based on just the end result.