# Why are vote counts (show down-votes) enabled only on Stack Overflow?

Tags: feature-request, privileges, vote-count

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is it a privilege to view vote counts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69852/why-is-it-a-privilege-to-view-vote-counts)

I've noticed that the vote splitter isn't available on the other stack exchange sites (including here on meta).  Is there a reason for this?  Please migrate it!

> [image]

Comment: You need a minimum amount of reputation to see it.

Answer (score 10):

You cannot see the exact vote breakdown until you have reached [the "established user"](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/established-user) reputation level, 1000 points.

At that point, you can click on the vote tally to see the up and down vote counts:

> [image: Vote counts]

Answer (score 4):

It *is* available to those with [enough reputation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/established-user).

Comment: Weird.  Is that in the FAQ?  Why limit it based on reputation?  I thought it was a recent feature and didn't realize it was because I only gained the privilege to see it.

Comment: It's been around for quite some time. It's only in the FAQ if you consider the privileges page (the page Oded linked) to be part of the FAQ, which is debatable.

Comment: yeah, but you need 20k rep to see the privileges page

Comment: @ChrisGerken - What do you mean? When you hover over your name in the header there is a link to this page in the popup. The page can be seen by anyone.

Answer (score 1):

It's available to those with [enough reputation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/established-user) because it's [computationally expensive to view the data](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/69854/151771).

Answer (score 0):

*Technically not an answer to the question, but still helpful.*

Vote counts are also available through the Stack Exchange API. The following script/extension/bookmarklet on Stack Apps adds this feature, even when you're not logged in:

> [“View Vote totals” without 1000 rep](https://stackapps.com/q/3082/9699?view-vote-totals-without-1000-rep)