# Any non-domain-specific privileges earned should be shared across all sites

Tags: feature-request, reputation, stack-exchange, privileges

If one examines the privileges earned above 100 reputation, they are split into two camps:

1. Privileges that are dangerous in the hands of someone unfamiliar with the domain.
2. Privileges that are simply rewards for good participation. These include:

   - [view close votes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/view-close-votes)
   - [established user](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/established-user) (*i.e. viewing up/down votes*)
   - viewing deleted posts (part of [moderator tools](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools))

My suggestion is that these passive privileges (and any future privileges of the same type) should be made available across all StackExchange accounts as soon as the necessary reputation is earned on *any* of the sites.

The fact that a user has earned sufficient reputation in another domain indicates they are probably of good character and a responsible user of the site. Hence, they should be trusted across all sites with non-dangerous privileges they've already earned.

I appreciate this may be difficult or impossible to implement as the current system is tightly wedded to one's per-site reputation, but I thought I'd raise the idea anyway.

Comment: I don't think that reducing ads fits in with the other two... Though I agree that reduced ads are good the ultimate purpose of the site is to make money so including it may make this less likely to be implemented.

Comment: I think all passive privileges should be cross-site. In particular I'd also like the ability to view deleted posts.

Comment: I'm torn, on the one hand I can understand your approach...on the other I really like the "proof yourself first, I don't care how much reputation you have on Stack Overflow, this is Sci-Fi, newb!"-approach.

Comment: @SulfurizedDemonbobby I think those feelings will still be felt when you can't edit question, retag, even vote down (initially). But it would be nice if StackExchange gave you a terse nod from the bar, like perhaps you belong here.

Comment: There should at least be some overlap between  privileges across the sites and privileges on this meta; partly because privileges already cross between each site and its associated meta, but also because, if someone has proven themselves on the stackexchange network, then their contributions and suggestions on suggested changes to the network should hold more weight. That's just my current take on it, though. I'm not vehement about it.

Answer (score 6):

Here's my take on it: The second type of privilege should be awarded cross-site, and not the first type. Let me explain why.

Say you have user ***x***, who has started a new account on StackOverflow. They are excited to earn reputation and help people! They earn around 200 reputation each day from honest upvotes and accepts, and without effort, in a month reach around 3k.

At this point, they discover other sites on the StackExchange network and thus create an account in Hinduism StackExchange, Physics StackExchange, Blender StackExchange, Photography StackExchange, and so on.

They first go onto their Hinduism account and click on a question. I'm sure after 1k rep, many people just get that habit of fetching the vote count. But for some reason, they cannot collect it here! After a second, they realize that they don't have enough rep to do so on Hinduism, since each site has a separate rep count.

But then, they think,

> *Why is it that I can't fetch vote counts? After all, there's no harm in it, and I can already fetch it on StackOverflow.*

---

Now, I know the established user example is not the best, but hopefully, you understand my point that reward privileges to the user should probably apply to all sites.

The second type of privilege (such as close-voting, delete-voting, etc) should ***not*** be applied on another site. To earn this type of privilege, you ***must*** earn the rep on that site. The reason for this would be because each site has a different topic, and site *x* would have different rules from site *y*.

Lastly, these are the *reward* privileges:

1. Reduce ads: Since you are already mature on one site, there is no reason to have ads on another.
2. View close votes on your own questions: Specifically not including the other part, which is to cast close votes on your own questions.
3. Established user
4. Seeing deleted answers: Only that part! The other part (such as having access to the NATO queue, etc) must be earned by gaining rep on the site itself.
5. Perhaps internal access to site analytics? I need more input on this one.

If this was possible programmatically, then I feel this would be a very good feature.

Comment: @charlietfl Really? I have 2.1k on SO, and I don't' see any ads. I didn't realise this question is 8 years old though :p.

Comment: @charlietfl i believe if you have greater than 200 rep then you have an option to disable ads. Perhaps it isn't ticked for you?

Comment: Checking vote counts without the "established user" privilege is still possible with [a userscript](https://stackapps.com/questions/3082/view-vote-totals-without-1000-rep). [Showing these counts is "expensive"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/69854/388884). Other than that, I agree.

Comment: @CaldeiraG Thanks for the script. I'll use it here on meta.