# Why upvotes and downvotes are not visible in sites other than stackoverflow.com

Tags: discussion, feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is it a privilege to view vote counts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69852/why-is-it-a-privilege-to-view-vote-counts)

I can see upvotes/downvotes total in Stackoverflow.com. But the same information seems unavailable in other sites (meta.stackoverflow.com, programmers.stackexchange.com, other stackexchange sites).

What is the reason this feature is not enabled of other sites?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot see the exact vote breakdown until you have reached [the "established user"](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/established-user) reputation level, 1000 points.

At that point, you can click on the vote tally to see the up and down vote counts:

> [image: Vote counts]

Comment: +1 Good answer. While i was searching for required level, you have posted with relevant link.

Comment: @Tilak hehe or you get the Chrome extension that allows you too see them all.

Comment: which chrome extension?

Comment: @Tilak See my answer ^_^

Answer (score 1):

You can always use [this Stack APP](https://stackapps.com/q/3082/9169).

It allows you to “View Vote totals” without 1000 rep.

I use it on quite a few sites :-)

It is very useful.

Comment: If the app is available, why 1000 rep are anyway required on SO? I think it should be removed

Comment: @Tilak so make it a feature request and don't was "why". But 1st look at the answer to the marked duplicate.