# How to permanently display a question's score, split into up/downvotes?

Tags: feature-request, support, vote-count, score

I recently hit 1k rep on SO, and so gained the [privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/established-user) of splitting the total score on a post, into its respective upvotes and downvotes.

Is there a way to get a question's score permanently displayed in this way? I seem to remember there was a user-script? I can't seem to find it now.

[image: a]

Comment: The system limits you to one query per second. So even if you had the script, there'd be significant lag before all the scores are expanded on a question with multiple answers.

Comment: @Mysticial Just for the question would be nice though... Nice going with the Pi thing btw ;)

Comment: I don't recall a UserScript for permanent display, only the one that just steals the information from the timeline of the post so users *without* the privilege can see them too.

Comment: @animuson That's the user-script I was referring to. It never worked for me at the time, I was hoping to try it again now that I have the priv... but I guess from your explanation of how it worked, it still won't work.

Comment: @animuson Please see the new answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that this requires 1k rep in the first place is that it is more expensive to get individual vote counts than it is to get the total +/- votes.

This would ruin the point of the privelege.

[Why is it a privilege to view vote counts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69852/why-is-it-a-privilege-to-view-vote-counts)