# Why seeing vote counts is harder to get than access to some review queues?

Tags: discussion, voting, privileges

[Why is it a privilege to view vote counts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69852) and its answer explains why seeing vote counts is a privilege (query cost + possibility for newbies to mess with votes).

Not allowing everyone to see these counts makes sense, but why is it so hard to get it?

You only have [to make half of these points](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) to have access to reviewing queues and I think that reviewing activity requires significant experience on SO, in order to do it right.

From my point of view, seeing vote counts is important because an answer with 50-47 clearly looks more problematic than one with 3-0.

Why was seeing vote counts set so high compared to other privileges (e.g. downvoting, accessing some review queues)?

Comment: what is the relation between seeing vote count and reviewing? FYI Your review should be independent. you should not downvote / upvote by checking it's present vote count

Comment: Theoretically, a privilege should be harder to get if it implies more power/responsibility. This is clearly debatable, but I think that reviewing means more power/responsibility that seeing vote counts (which is a read-only action and vote abusing is detected anyway).

Comment: So, what likely happened is that they looked at the query cost, looked at how many users would have the privilege and certain rep levels, and picked a number where they would be unlikely to pay the cost a large number of times. If, say, 10 000 people have 2k+ rep, and 1 000 000 people have less than that, then giving access to 2k+ rep would mean only a max of 10 000 hits in any given moment. Giving it to lower rep users would increase the max number of hits, potentially incurring a large overhead.