# Why is the "Show vote summaries" filter not available to anonymous users?

Tags: support, timeline, anonymous-visitors

I was just checking the timeline of a post on a site where I don't have an account, and I noticed that the "Show vote summaries" filter option is unavailable.

Here's an example of what the timeline looks like when logged in vs. browsing anonymously:

**Logged in:**

[image: Logged in]

**Anonymous visitor:**

[image: Anonymous]

Is there any reason for this?

Comment: Loosely related: ["Vote summaries" are confusing if you don't have the "established user" privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/380874/vote-summaries-are-confusing-if-you-dont-have-the-established-user-privileg)

Comment: A possible duplicate of, but I'm not absolutely certain: [Why is it a privilege to view vote counts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69852/why-is-it-a-privilege-to-view-vote-counts?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: @Mari Re _"possible duplicate"_: No, that's different. That one is talking about vote breakdowns on the Q&A page (which is tied to a certain privilege) while this question is about vote summaries on the Timeline page. This is currently no restrictions based on privilege or reputation level.

Comment: Like I said, I wasn't sure. Privilege to view voting timelines could possibly be limited to registered users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These values are not cached and are counted on-the-fly when you request the timeline page with summaries. For the same performance reasons as anonymous users get restricted elsewhere on the site (like searching), we didn't want to perform that counting for anonymous users.

Comment: Hmm, is the timeline, in general, being used that often by anonymous users anyway? If not, then perhaps removing this restriction would be beneficial to experienced users who happen to be logged out, or not registered on a specific site, in my opinion.

Comment: It's not about how often it gets used, it's about preventing a method of attack. Most users, even logged in, don't often perform searches for 50 tags at a time, but it's still something you don't want to *have available* to be hammered if anyone discovers it and feels like hammering it. So no, we won't lift that restriction.