# Separate numbers/score for positive and negative votes for each question or answer

Tags: feature-request, voting, down-votes, up-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Show Total Votes (or Up/Down Votes)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/747/show-total-votes-or-up-down-votes)

I think it would be better to have separate numbers showing upvotes and downvotes so that its clear on how many upvotes/downvotes are casted on a particular question/answer.

What does the community think?

Comment: Take a look at [Show Total Votes (or Up/Down Votes)][1]


  [1]: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/747/show-total-votes-or-up-down-votes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is *implemented* as the [“View vote count”](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/view-vote-counts) privilege.
If you have enough reputation (1000) you can click on the score of a post to show the numbers of upvotes and downvotes.