# How much reputation is required to see close vote counts?

Tags: support, reputation, vote-to-close, privileges

How much reputation is required to see close vote counts?

Edit:

With a background on the MSO question *[Separate numbers/score for positive and negative votes for each question or answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74419)* I was told that it is wrong to answer duplicate questions, and my answer was downvoted.
I was wondering why I didn't see a close vote count in this case.

I thought this requires the privilege **[View close votes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/view-close-votes)**.

Comment: Related: [view close votes](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/view-close-votes) is listed as requiring 250 rep on meta. I have 250, but I can't view close votes. At least, I've never seen the `close` link or anything like it here.

Comment: @marcog Good catch, it's the same [on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/view-close-votes). I think that privilege is titled wrong; it's talking about the ability to cast close/reopen votes on your own questions. There is no separate privilege that I know of to just view close votes without being able to cast them. You might want to post this as a [separate bug report](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?title=Incorrect%20privileges%20entry&tags=bug+privileges)

Comment: @Michael Found an [existing bug report](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68512/is-the-explanation-of-view-close-votes-misleading), where the content was clarified but not the name. Perhaps the name could also be clarified, e.g. "view close votes on your questions".

Comment: @marcog I think Gnome was right, it should be "Vote to close, reopen, or migrate your questions" like in the FAQ. I'll ask the privileges developer about it tomorrow if a dev doesn't see this first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You see them if you can [cast](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/close-questions) them.

Comment: The [privileges page](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/view-close-votes) says otherwise...

Comment: @John, read the entire page, (and see mario's and my commment on your answer).

Answer (score 1):

According to the [privileges page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/view-close-votes), the reputation required to view close votes is 250, and the required rep to *cast* close votes is 3000.

Comment: The 250 actually only allows you to see closevotes on your own question.

Comment: from the privileges page: "You may also cast a close or reopen vote on your questions. With the close/reopen vote privilege, you'll be able to see (and cast) close and reopen votes on all questions."

Comment: @game that might be an error in the privileges page text, and we should correct it.

Comment: @Jeff: So what is correct?  Can you only see your own at 250 or can you see all?