# Show that people have voted on a question to stop equal up/down votes hiding this fact

Tags: feature-request, voting

I recently posted a question on SO which got an equal number of upvotes and downvotes. Therefore, the vote counter remained at zero.

I have enough rep to see the split +2/-2, but because the counter was showing zero I hadn't realised that people had voted.

Does the counter change its appearance at all once someone has voted? If not, perhaps it should, to highlight this fact?

Comment: Aye nice suggestion. Its those little things that can change a lot :)

Comment: I like that. Did anyone already look how many questions would be currently affected?

Comment: Didn't you notice the change to your rep? +2/-2 is +16, and if you clicked your recent summary you'd see both up votes and down votes in the reputation tab.

Comment: I did notice the change to my rep, but it hadn't occurred to me that it was for the question in question. I assumed it was from other questions - I've been quite active on SO recently so it would've got lost in the noise.

Comment: @Andy actually +2 and -2 means total of 6 reputation, upvote on question give only 5 points. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very nice suggestion indeed. Adding on to the OP's suggestion, I think we can have something like `show the number(votes) in different color if there are equal number of upvotes and downvotes`.

This is concern only when the votes show up as 0 (equal upvotes and downvotes). I wonder if this feature would be required in any other case tough.

Comment: If there are up- and downvotes, the count shown is off, so it concerns a lot of questions (and answers too, of course).

Answer (score 3):

Sort of like this?

[Show Total Votes (or Up/Down Votes)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/747/show-total-votes-or-up-down-votes)

[image]

Comment: Yes, what is proposed in that question would be good, what is described as being deployed in the accepted answer is precisely what caused the problem I had.