# Vote counts fold when AJAX update occurs

Tags: bug, vote-count, live-refresh

When expanding the vote score into vote counts like the image below, it folds again when the score gets updated.

Can you please update the vote counts without folding the votes again?

[image: Expanded vote counts]

Comment: I think the update only gives you the total, so it has to fold the vote count. Besides, there's a rate limit on fetching vote counts (once per second) and the live updates happen much more often than that.

Comment: I think the live updates occur more often *only when applicable*. (It's not like polling.) At that point, [maybe the vote count is available too](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/747/show-total-votes-or-up-down-votes/1007#1007), @NullUserException, hence without the need to get the exact figures?

Comment: @Arjan - I can't think of a good technical reason why the up and down counts _wouldn't_ be available, so it's really just a matter of implementation. It _does_ add more to the payload, however.

Comment: Well, maybe while adding a vote to the vote table, the number of other votes is still not used, hence not queried/available, @cdeszaq. But: I don't know for sure either of course.