# Why Up/Down Votes only visible for Established users?

Tags: discussion, voting, privileges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do vote-counts require 1,000 reputation to see?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37116/why-do-vote-counts-require-1-000-reputation-to-see)

I don't mind not knowing the count of both but was just curious why it's so high up in the list of privileges?

Is it more of a tool for established users to use if the post is getting up votes even though the total is negative?

Comment: Wow thanks. Strange that didn't show up in my search -.-

Comment: There have also been requests to [allow low-rep users to see the counts for their own posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40480/please-enable-low-rep-users-to-easily-breakout-up-and-down-votes-on-their-own-qu), rather than having to manually piece this together from their rep history, and to [expose the vote counts without requiring a click](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/747/show-total-votes-or-up-down-votes/). But those have been declined. Also related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147664/vote-count-1-up-1-down-should-be-2

Comment: Hmm yea I could see why they wouldn't want that. Thanks for the extended research!