# Hide upvotes and downvotes totals after another click

Tags: feature-request, voting, vote-count

We already know that you can [see how many upvotes/downvotes are casted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/747/159127) to a question/answer by clicking on the the number of votes (if you are privileged to do so).

It would be even better if another click would hide upvotes/downvotes count and show the ordinary sum number.

It's obviously trivial, but would be more comfortable.

Comment: I *highly* doubt this'll get implemented, as you can simply refresh the page to hide it. But sure, I agree. It'd be more comfortable. =)

Comment: For those with OCD or like their page to be neat and tidy, this could save lives.

Answer (score 2):

That would be nice, but here are some workarounds:

- Refreshing will reset the effect.
- Voting (either up or down, even if you've voted before and your vote is locked) will reset the effect for that post.

I doubt this to be high on the list of feature implementations, but you never know.