# How do you view vote history for a question or answer? or Add some sort of vote activity indicator?

Tags: feature-request, voting, vote-count, timeline

I recently posted an answer that was a little controversial, I suppose.  While watching the page the answer was voted up and down a few times.  Is there a way to view the vote history?  Also, would there be any support for adding some sort of activity indicator?  My reasoning is this, you could potentially have a question or answer with "0 votes" that actually had numerous votes.  Visually seeing 0 votes indicates the question hasn't had any attention when exactly the opposite could be the case.

Thoughts?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/183981/timeline

Comment: I see, how do you access that from the interface?

Comment: There's a privilege at 2k? rep that lets you see the breakdown of up and downvotes on a post, rather than just the net score.

Comment: You don't.  You can only access through URL hackery.

Comment: So are these two "features" one and the same? ie, does the 2k perk mentioned = /timeline?

Comment: They are unrelated features.

Comment: That's frustrating.

Comment: Is the url hack possible for answers?

Comment: It shows details about both questions and all answers to that question on that same page.

Comment: ahh, it groups all the answers and shows the combined up/down votes.  Am I seeing that right?

Comment: Found this question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/747/show-total-votes-or-up-down-votes?rq=1 apparently it's meta only right now and it's 1k rep, not 2k

Comment: I wasn't sure if it was one or two, but it's not specific to meta; it's been on every site for many years.

Comment: Irrelevant now: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/view-vote-totals-without/oibfliilcglieepgkdkahpfiiigdijdd  Woot!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[This userscript](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/6192-stack-exchange-view-vote-totals-without-1000-rep) shows the vote distribution when pressing the score, also available as a [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/view-vote-totals-without/oibfliilcglieepgkdkahpfiiigdijdd).

[image: screenshot]

StackApps: ["View Vote totals" without 1000 rep](https://stackapps.com/questions/3082/view-vote-totals-without-1000-rep/)

Comment: FYI relying on bugs is just begging for them to be fixed eventually.

Comment: @Servy What do you mean by "bugs"? That extension doesn't depend on any bugs to get vote totals, but uses the official [Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/).