# How can I see the number of up / down votes on my own posts without 1000 rep?

Tags: support, score

I would really like to be able to see my own post's score. How can I do this?

<del>This is different from [How do you view vote history for a question or answer? or Add some sort of vote activity indicator?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183981/how-do-you-view-vote-history-for-a-question-or-answer-or-add-some-sort-of-vote) because I only want to see what it is now.</del>

Comment: Simply view the timeline.

Comment: Ohh, didn't realise that :)

Comment: @Tim Look at the accepted answer to that question and compare it to you own accepted answer. I guess the title of that question should be changed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Personally I am using [this](https://stackapps.com/questions/3082/view-vote-totals-without-1000-rep) script installed on Tamper Monkey. Works wonderfully.

Also it works in `/review` and `/questions` (somewhere else probably) pages if you replace complicated `@include`s and `@exclude`s  with these simple `@include`s , as I did after installation:

```
// @include        *://*.stackexchange.com/*
// @include        *://*stackoverflow.com/*
// @include        *://*serverfault.com/*
// @include        *://*superuser.com/*
// @include        *://*askubuntu.com/*
// @include        *://*stackapps.com/*
// @include        *://*mathoverflow.net/*
```

How it'd look, before you test :D

> [image] [image]

Answer (score 3):

Use this handy table, or the code snippet below:

```
┌──────────┬────────────┬────────────┬──────────┬─────────────┬───────┐
│ Up Votes │ Down Votes │ Rep Gained │ Rep Lost │ Overall Rep │ Score │
├──────────┼────────────┼────────────┼──────────┼─────────────┼───────┤
│          │            │            │          │             │       │
│        0 │          0 │          0 │        0 │           0 │     0 │
│        1 │          0 │          5 │        0 │           5 │     1 │
│        2 │          0 │         10 │        0 │          10 │     2 │
│        3 │          0 │         15 │        0 │          15 │     3 │
│        4 │          0 │         20 │        0 │          20 │     4 │
│        5 │          0 │         25 │        0 │          25 │     5 │
│        0 │          1 │          0 │        2 │          ─2 │    ─1 │
│        1 │          1 │          5 │        2 │           3 │     0 │
│        2 │          1 │         10 │        2 │           8 │     1 │
│        3 │          1 │         15 │        2 │          13 │     2 │
│        4 │          1 │         20 │        2 │          18 │     3 │
│        5 │          1 │         25 │        2 │          23 │     4 │
│        0 │          2 │          0 │        4 │          ─4 │    ─2 │
│        1 │          2 │          5 │        4 │           1 │    ─1 │
│        2 │          2 │         10 │        4 │           6 │     0 │
│        3 │          2 │         15 │        4 │          11 │     1 │
│        4 │          2 │         20 │        4 │          16 │     2 │
│        5 │          2 │         25 │        4 │          21 │     3 │
│        0 │          3 │          0 │        6 │          ─6 │    ─3 │
│        1 │          3 │          5 │        6 │          ─1 │    ─2 │
│        2 │          3 │         10 │        6 │           4 │    ─1 │
│        3 │          3 │         15 │        6 │           9 │     0 │
│        4 │          3 │         20 │        6 │          14 │     1 │
│        5 │          3 │         25 │        6 │          19 │     2 │
│        0 │          4 │          0 │        8 │          ─8 │    ─4 │
│        1 │          4 │          5 │        8 │          ─3 │    ─3 │
│        2 │          4 │         10 │        8 │           2 │    ─2 │
│        3 │          4 │         15 │        8 │           7 │    ─1 │
│        4 │          4 │         20 │        8 │          12 │     0 │
│        5 │          4 │         25 │        8 │          17 │     1 │
│        0 │          5 │          0 │       10 │         ─10 │    ─5 │
│        1 │          5 │          5 │       10 │          ─5 │    ─4 │
│        2 │          5 │         10 │       10 │           0 │    ─3 │
│        3 │          5 │         15 │       10 │           5 │    ─2 │
│        4 │          5 │         20 │       10 │          10 │    ─1 │
│        5 │          5 │         25 │       10 │          15 │     0 │
└──────────┴────────────┴────────────┴──────────┴─────────────┴───────┘
```

Look for the rep you have gained / lost and the score of the post, to find the up / down votes.

Use this snippet for bigger scores / rep changes. Enter the rep you have and the score of the post and voilla!

```js
function submit() {
  var score = parseInt(document.getElementById("score").value);
  var rep = parseInt(document.getElementById("rep").value);
  
  u = (rep-(score *2))/3
  d = (rep-(score *5))/3
  
  if (u % 1 != 0) {
    alert('That situation can\'t occur.');
  } else if (d % 1 != 0) {
    alert('That situation can\'t occur.');
  } else {
    alert('Up votes: '+ u + '\nDown votes: ' + d);
  }
}
```

```html
Score:
<input type="number" name="score" id="score">
<br>Rep:
<input type="number" name="rep" id="rep">
<br>
<input type="button" value="send" onclick="submit()">
```

Comment: Actually this is quite an interesting snippet, where I can imitate different scores with different rep :) But actually if the post is old, it is quite difficult to search votes on it through your rep page :D

Comment: And now I know the way I can reach the rep cap having my post floating near 0: http://i.stack.imgur.com/vDMX2.png :D

Comment: Your algorithm can be improved: you can directly calcuate `u=(rep-score*2)/3` and `d=(rep-score*5)/3`.