# How should I behave when I see a feature request I consider unnecessary/useless?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, etiquette

When you think that a feature request in a question should not be implemented (e.g. because you do not agree with the motivations provided) should you do either/both:

- Downvote the question, so that by keeping a low score, it's clear it should not be implemented? Or
- Answer motivating why the feature request is not valid, or upvote an already present answer?

Comment: Just hang around meta and your will see how the regulars act. That should give you your answer over time. There are far to many variables to answer. You could stop both, or either, or neither. All depends.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I can see only total scores, not by how many up and down votes was composed.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Many might explain in the comments why they disagree, but that won't say if they downvoted or not

Comment: You don't need to see vote splits to see how people act. Don't be so worried about how to act right away. Just pay attention and you'll figure it out. The idea of when to vote, answer, comment, or some combination of all 3 will come with experience

Comment: @Antonio: See [How can I see the number of up / down votes on my own posts without 1000 rep?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251796/168244)

Comment: @Werner, thanks, but Psubsee2003 suggested to study the general behaviour of regulars towards feature requests questions, and I can only do that by checking questions asked by other people.

Comment: @psubsee2003 And this question got downvoted because...?

Comment: @Antonio: I know that. You mentioned though that you can't see up/down-votes per post, only (total) score. The linked post shows how you can achieve this.

Comment: @Werner Only on my own posts, correct?

Comment: @Antonio: No. Timeline viewing is available to all.

Comment: @Werner Amazing! :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [When should I vote?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250876/245360)

Comment: @PatrickHofman I believe there the answer was very hidden (in [a secondary answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250876/225842)), while here it's very clear, but ok.

Comment: @ant true. I added it a while ago since it was missing from that post. It is in like with the faq though.

Comment: @Robert: Why was this reopened?

Comment: @PatrickHofman Because of flags making the case that this is largely a different question than "how to vote" on the general Q&A. *"Voting on meta is different"* is the case that is often made here, so it seemed reasonable and warranted to have a different discussion. Not a duplicate.

Comment: @RobertCartaino: That is covered in the dup too, right?

Comment: @PatrickHofman Only coincidentally, but that doesn't preclude a separate answer or discussion here.

Comment: @RobertCartaino Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The "What's Meta" [page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta) says:

> **On posts tagged feature-request, voting indicates agreement or disagreement** with the proposed change rather than just the quality or usefulness of the post itself.

(Emphasis in the original.)

People are voting such posts to indicate whether the feature should be implemented. You can vote like other folks do.

As with all other votes you cast on SE sites, it is not necessary to comment or answer when you vote. My personal guideline as to whether to answer is: a) should the post be answered, and b) has no one already provided the answer I'd give? It is hard to give a comprehensive set of rules regarding what post should be answered but in brief if the post is well-written and the proposal has a fault that the OP is likely to not have foreseen, then it merits an answer.