# Inspection of vote history for reputation compensation

Tags: feature-request, reputation, voting

#### Requested Feature

I suggest to monitor questions with [too] negative scores whose score elevates and reach zero or positive (*See note 1*), then from the participating down voters, a set amount of RP be deduct as a compensation (*See note 2*).

#### Notes

1. Setting some restrictions may be meaningful though, such as the elevation be made during limited time and limited number of revisions made meanwhile.
2. With a rationale similar to when we loose reputation on withdrawing some of our previous actions (e.g.: un-accepting an answer).

#### In Reply to comments / answers (NEW)

The 30 min culture of returning back to the down-voted question mentioned by *Patrick* is a nice behavior and if the majority of users would behave so, I would not need to suggest the feature. The point that *Dan* emphasizes upon could solve the problem of asking terrible question then editing it back to be an excellent one, but the constraint could more specific and for example limit the number of changed bytes instead of number of revisions.

*Glorfindel*'s point for reverse situation is still a good subject for discussion.

The points that *Cai* and *Patrick* mentioned, also hints me to some replacement feature request:
*auto-annulment of un-confirmed down-votes after 30 mins for re-edited posts* (Posts with down-votes if edited sooner than elapse of 30 minutes from the down-vote keep that vote only if it is confirmed by originator after the edit happened).

Now lets go to benefits. This mechanism could improve voting quality. That is one would not down-vote a question that could be fixed with a very minor change. In other words, if you see a very minor mistake, fix it instead of down-voting it (the originators are still able to nullify the change if it diverges the question from their intention because of such fixes or keep it if it is improved).

#### Related Resources

- [How do you view vote history for a question or answer? or Add some sort of vote activity indicator?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183981/how-do-you-view-vote-history-for-a-question-or-answer-or-add-some-sort-of-vote)

Comment: So what you're essentially saying is dowvote reputation gains or losses should be reversed if the overall score of a post reverses?

Comment: Why do you want this? **What are the benefits?** And should the same be done for the reverse situation, e.g. if you upvote a question that later receives a negative score?

Comment: Unless the "limited number of revisions" is precisely 0, I don't know how you can confidently discount a user's vote on the question as he initially saw it. And frankly I will be skeptical of any proposal which tends to discourage downvoting (which we need as badly as upvoting), unless the benefits are clearly spelled out and outweigh the losses. People are already too protective of their rep.

Comment: Dear friends, I hope I have cumulatively considered and answered your questions in the NEW section.

Comment: No.  People don't downvote enough as is.  Punishing them for trying to keep quality high is counter productive.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> then from the participating down voters, a set amount of RP be deduct as a compensation

So if I got you right, you want to punish users who downvoted at some time after a post gets upvotes? What about this scenario: a user asks a terrible bad question, it gets downvoted and eventually it is closed, as it should. The author edits it and it gets upvotes and reopen votes. Are the downvotes suddenly bad? No. Those users voted on the question as it was back then.

Usually, if I downvote a post I stick for about 30 minutes to see if it recovers, if not, I don't visit unless someone comment pings me.

Users could forced to downvoted posts regularly, but I don't think that is really feasible. If I had to go over the thousands of votes (up or down) to check if they are still valid, it would take me a year to go over all them.

The lesson authors learn is this: do it right or don't do it. No need to punish the downvoters.

Comment: I now have recognize the consensus of the community and appreciate that. Thanks for answering. In fact that is a nice culture to check-back manually and undo the down-vote upon improvement of quality. Do you see any positive points in requesting my feature in a more friendly manner (than punishing the voter): such as an automatic undo mechanism upon not confirming the down-vote after receiving a confirmation request during 30 minutes of logged in activity of the voter provided that the voted-on content has been changed.

Comment: The problem is clearly there, you can't deny that, but an actual solution is hard. Just discarding downvotes after an edit is nonsense. I will keep editing my posts until the downvoters have lost interest. There is just one fix: ask it right the first time.