# Vote +/- visible from question timeline for < 1000 rep users

Tags: discussion, reputation, privileges, timeline

I've noticed by looking by the timeline on this question ([17061931](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/17061931/timeline)) that I was able to see the + and - votes for my answer on that question, even though [on the privileges page](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges) it says that to view vote counts that I need to get 1000 rep.  Is this a bug, or is this some reward for hunting effort?

Just for reference, I found one from the "featured" pile and tested it - it also worked: [16878938](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/16878938/timeline).

Comment: Primarily, if I recall, the reason vote splits are hidden in the first place is because it's an expensive query. If you're querying for the entire timeline anyway, then best be complete about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't a bug. The main reason the rep privilege is in place is to limit vote count queries (see https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/1007/192187).

Viewing vote counts without 1000 rep is perfectly fine. There's even an extension for it (["View Vote totals" without 1000 rep](https://stackapps.com/questions/3082/view-vote-totals-without-1000-rep)). No need to worry.