# What is the rationale for restricting vote split views to 1000 rep?

Tags: discussion, privileges

When I join a new site, one of my biggest pet peeves is that I cannot see the vote split on a question and/or answer.  This feature is a great education - a +5 / -4 answer tells me a lot more about the consensus of "on-topic" is then a simple +1.  And yet, the feature waits until you have 1000 rep, which is a fairly significant hurdle.

So, why did this feature get put so high on the cookie shelf anyway?

Comment: Because it costs a lot of performance and not everyone should be able to trigger it.

Comment: Basically, performance reasons. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/747/show-total-votes-or-up-down-votes/1007#1007

Comment: You probably already know this, but you can still view the vote counts by looking at the timeline. Just replace "questions" with "posts" and the question title with "timeline" in the URL. So http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/253/is-it-inappropriate-to-add-a-religious-title-on-the-top-line-of-your-resume would become http://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/253/timeline. Of course, you'd need to tally up the total vote count yourself.

Comment: I was unaware of that. Yay and thank you.