# Let me collapse the votes breakdown after expanding it

Tags: feature-request, voting, down-votes, user-interface, up-votes

This is pretty trivial, but why is it not possible to un-display the up/down vote breakdown on questions and answers here? I found the simplest workaround is to refresh the page. Another clunky workaround is to up or down vote. It seems like a simple enough feature add to revert to the previous view.

I wouldn't think a re-query of the database would be necessary for this functionality. It would save more on performance than a refresh. The reason I speak of performance is because of the implementation of it in the first place: [Show Total Votes (or Up/Down Votes)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/747/show-total-votes-or-up-down-votes)

Being able to revert to prior information just "feels right" to me on a well-designed webpage so I'm surprised SE doesn't have this simple capability.

Comment: We call "Vote Totals" Pandora's Box for a reason.

Comment: It's consistent with other things that you can expand but can't collapse, e.g. "add comment", "more hot questions" and more.

Answer (score 1):

You can collapse the vote breakdown by up-/down-voting or attempting to vote. If you have not previously voted or previously voted and your vote is not locked-in, and you don't want to change the current state of your vote/non-vote, then you can immediately reverse the vote/un-vote which you perform to collapse the vote breakdown. If you've already voted and your vote is locked, or it's your own post, then you'll get a warning that you can't vote, but the vote breakdown will be collapsed.

The breakdown is also automatically collapsed when the score is updated by the system via the WebSocket (i.e. when someone else votes).

Here's what it looks like:

[image]

Comment: It appears you're slightly expanding on a point I already made in the question?
"Another clunky workaround is to up or down vote."

Comment: Interestingly, I managed to just skim over that sentence in the question. OTOH, making it clear to people who read the question that what you're asking for is actually already possible, but just not obvious and may take two clicks, seems reasonable. If the Community user hadn't bumped this question to the home page ([twice now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/236767/timeline)), I must admit that I wouldn't have even been aware of this question, let alone answered it.

Answer (score 0):

In the iOS app this is possible. Holding down on the score displays the vote breakdown and tapping the breakdown reverts it to the score.

Answer (score -1):

This is trivially possible already. In fact, there's a shortcut key for it: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> (may be different on heathen systems).

Comment: That is a refresh isn't it? That incurs the processing penalty hit the designers were trying to avoid in the first place as seen in the link I provided.