# Add an explanatory tooltip to the question's score and number of stars

Tags: feature-request, tooltips, score

On the left of each question, add a tooltip (i.e. `title` attribute) to the number with the score (up/down votes result) and the number of people who starred this. Suggested wordings:

- "Question's voting score"
- "Number of users who starred this question"

This can help newbie users to figure out what these number mean.

EDIT after comments (@JonW):

Looks like this feature is already in place, it's just not working for me (Firefox). My source code is:

```
<span itemprop="upvoteCount" class="vote-count-post ">0</span>
```

According to @PeterJ the tooltip is only shown when you have 1000 reputation. This is ridiculous! An explanation provided just for the experts, not for the newbies?!?

This is not a duplicate of [Show Total Votes (or Up/Down Votes)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/747/show-total-votes-or-up-down-votes); I'm asking just to include a **tooltip** to an already existing information.

Comment: Um, that exists already. Unless I'm misunderstanding this question.

Comment: On this page itself, when I hover the `0` (between the up/down vote arrow button) I don't get any tooltip (in Firefox). On the buttons I do get a tooltip.

Comment: There is one in there too. Check the source: `<span itemprop="upvoteCount" class="vote-count-post " title="View upvote and downvote totals" style="cursor: pointer;">0</span>`

Comment: @JonW That's blank when you have < 1000 rep (because you can't see vote splits)

Answer (score 3):

It seems this indeed isn't implemented yet. If you don't have enough reputation to see votes, you won't see the tooltip either. There is just none defined.

I agree this would be useful to other users, maybe instead of a tooltip we should give more information, something in the line of:

> Once you have [enough reputation][LINK], you can see the upvotes and downvotes totals.

Where [LINK] links to the [Established user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/established-user) privilege page. This would be helpful to new users that want to know how to achieve that privilege.