# Can I see total votes on mobile website?

Tags: feature-request, support, user-interface, mobile-web, vote-count

Verified [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/747) on desktop. But on mobile web it made me give an up vote, so there's no "click on number".

Are we going to be able to view total votes on mobile using a browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my Android mobile in the Stack Exchange App, simply **pressing and holding** the number of votes will trigger a pop-up showing the number of up and down votes. *(Unfortunately I can't post a screen shot because the dialog disappears when I try to capture it.)*

Alternately, on my Android in Chrome you can view total votes by switching to "full site" view using the link at the bottom of every page, then **touch any vote count** to see total votes:

[image]

As noted [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/1007/271445) you must have 1000 rep on a site to see up and down votes.

Comment: Are you talking about mobile web or app?

Comment: @alexolut Good question; mobile app. I'll update my answer

Comment: You are using full web version of site. Follow the link "mobile" in the page footer.

Comment: @alexolut I am intentionally using the full site. In the mobile site the vote counts do not work.

Comment: OP question is about [tag:mobile-web] site.

Comment: So no solution on mobile **website** by far?

Comment: @iBug To my knowledge, the two methods for viewing total votes I've described are the only ways to do so on mobile.

Comment: @Twisty Got it ✔ Accept