# Total Up and Down votes in posts table

Tags: feature-request, voting, information-display, database

There is a limitation in showing the up and down votes seperately for posts: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/1007/389297

The reason is that it requires looking up the votes table in the database, which is costly.

But if it is something that gets requested a lot then what about putting an aggregate counter from both the up and down votes table into the posts table? This will in reduce the cost of the requests. If you can do it for the net 'up minus down' score then you could do it, with little extra cost, for the two up and down scores separately (or you record total votes, which only requires one extra field).

Comment: Note that there is a userscript that allows sub-1k users to see vote split: https://stackapps.com/questions/3082/view-vote-totals-without-1000-rep