# A display of a post's score shouldn't claim to be a display of the post's number of votes

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, score, activity

On certain tabs in your activity page, there is a number next to a post which is labeled as referring to the number of votes. For example, in the Bounties tab:

[image: Screenshot of bounties tab]

However, this is not quite an accurate description. The number displayed there is actually the post's *score*, rather than the number of votes that the post has. In the above example, it says that there are 8 votes, but if we open the question we see that there are actually 10 upvotes and 2 downvotes for a total of 12 (not 8) votes:

[image: Screenshot of question score]

The same issue exists in the Questions tab. For instance:

[image: Screenshot of questions tab]

Here the display tells us that the question has -2 votes. Aside from the fact that having a negative amount of votes is impossible, when we open this question we find that it actually has a whopping 20 votes:

[image: Screenshot of question score]

The Answers tab has an additional twist. Here there is a hover text that explicitly states that the number displayed is the *total* number of votes on the answer:

[image: Screenshot of Answers tab]

Yet once again this is entirely inaccurate, as opening the answer shows that there are actually 32 total votes on this answer:

[image: Screenshot of answer score]

The simplest solution here would be to change the label, so that instead of saying that it is displaying the number of votes it will say that it is displaying the score.

Can this be implemented?

Comment: Related post from 10 years ago - [Show Total Votes (or Up/Down Votes)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/747/show-total-votes-or-up-down-votes/)